# How to gather task results in Trio?

Tags: python-3.x, python-trio

I wrote a script that uses a nursery and the asks module to loop through and call an API based upon the loop variables.  I get responses but don't know how to return the data like you would with asyncio.

I also have a question on limiting the APIs to 5 per second.

```
from datetime import datetime
import asks
import time
import trio

asks.init("trio")
s = asks.Session(connections=4)

async def main():
    start_time = time.time()

    api_key = 'API-KEY'
    org_id = 'ORG-ID'
    networkIds = ['id1','id2','idn']

    url = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/{0}/airMarshal?timespan=3600'
    headers = {'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': api_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        for i in networkIds:
            nursery.start_soon(fetch, url.format(i), headers)

    print("Total time:", time.time() - start_time)



async def fetch(url, headers):
    print("Start: ", url)
    response = await s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print("Finished: ", url, len(response.content), response.status_code)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

When I run nursery.start_soon(fetch...) , I am printing data within fetch, but how do I return the data?  I didn't see anything similar to asyncio.gather(*tasks) function.

Also, I can limit the number of sessions to 1-4, which helps get down below the 5 API per second limit, but was wondering if there was a built in way to ensure that no more than 5 APIs get called in any given second?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  
Take a look at initial attemp on github: https://github.com/jleatham/Meraki-findClient-async/blob/master/findClient.py
Doesn't use queues, but limits the calls to below 5 APIs per second and retries any 429 responses.  Code is very specific/ugly but could be modified for general API handling.

Comment: A gather function https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/1089#issuecomment-521916733

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning data: pass the networkID and a dict to the `fetch` tasks:

```
async def main():
    …
    results = {}
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        for i in networkIds:
            nursery.start_soon(fetch, url.format(i), headers, results, i)
    ## results are available here

async def fetch(url, headers, results, i):
    print("Start: ", url)
    response = await s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print("Finished: ", url, len(response.content), response.status_code)
    results[i] = response
```

Alternately, create a `trio.Queue` to which you `put` the results; your main task can then read the results from the queue.

API limit: create a `trio.Queue(10)` and start a task along these lines:

```
async def limiter(queue):
    while True:
        await trio.sleep(0.2)
        await queue.put(None)
```

Pass that queue to `fetch`, as another argument, and call `await limit_queue.get()` before each API call.

Comment: I am trying to unpack your answer, not quite understanding how to integrate into my code.  I'll take a look at the .Event / .queue / and .sleep functions in the documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I got the results back using this method, I can work with that.  Still working on getting the queue integrated into my code.  I googled and didn't see a single example of trio.queue being used.  How do I pass the limiter(queue) to fetch?  Thanks so far!

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. You don't pass `limiter(queue)` to `fetch` – you simply pass the queue which you use for limiting to `fetch`, as another argument.

Comment: Love your limiter queue! That's a model I hadn't seen before.

Comment: Note that Trio deprecated Queue in favour of open_memory_channel: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/history.html?highlight=trio.Queue#id40
See this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650112/5428609

Answer (score 6):

Technically, `trio.Queue` has been deprecated in trio 0.9. It has been replaced by [`trio.open_memory_channel`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#trio.open_memory_channel).

Short example:

```
sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(len(networkIds)
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    for i in networkIds:
        nursery.start_soon(fetch, sender, url.format(i), headers)

async for value in receiver:
    # Do your job here
    pass
```

And in your `fetch` function you should call `async sender.send(value)` somewhere.

Comment: also have to call the channels as a context manager with `async with sender` and `async with receiver` before sending and receiving values. See here: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#clean-shutdown-with-channels

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671541/1720199), you can define the following function:

```py
async def gather(*tasks):

    async def collect(index, task, results):
        task_func, *task_args = task
        results[index] = await task_func(*task_args)

    results = {}
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        for index, task in enumerate(tasks):
            nursery.start_soon(collect, index, task, results)
    return [results[i] for i in range(len(tasks))]
```

You can then use trio in the exact same way as asyncio by simply patching trio (adding the gather function):

```py
import trio
trio.gather = gather
```

Here is a practical example:

```py
async def child(x):
    print(f"Child sleeping {x}")
    await trio.sleep(x)
    return 2*x

async def parent():
    tasks = [(child, t) for t in range(3)]
    return await trio.gather(*tasks)

print("results:", trio.run(parent))
```

Comment: Trio allows for task communication by using `open_memory_channel`: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html?highlight=trio.Queue#using-channels-to-pass-values-between-tasks. It'd be better to use this functionality rather than monkey patching in a work around. The channels have the advantage of passing values generatively, rather than your `gather` implementation which hold all values in memory before returning to the caller.

Comment: @Luke Purnell That misses the point, the point is to gather the results into a single place *after* the concurrency is completed and exited, *outside* the nursery execution scope (with statement). By definition, memory channels are between tasks inside nursery scopes, so it's a completely different thing.

Comment: I still don't see the need for this gather function. If you need the behaviour you've describer, then you could use a list created outside the nursery and append to it from within the memory channel receiver.

Answer (score 5):

> When I run nursery.start_soon(fetch...) , I am printing data within fetch, but how do I return the data? I didn't see anything similar to asyncio.gather(*tasks) function.

You're asking two different questions, so I'll just answer this one. Matthias already answered your other question.

When you call `start_soon()`, you are asking Trio to run the task in the background, and then keep going. This is why Trio is able to run `fetch()` several times concurrently. But because Trio keeps going, there is no way to "return" the result the way a Python function normally would. where would it even return to?

You can use a queue to let `fetch()` tasks send results to another task for additional processing.

To create a queue:

```
response_queue = trio.Queue(capacity=len(networkIds))
```

When you start your fetch tasks, pass the queue as an argument and send a sentintel to the queue when you're done:

```
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    for i in networkIds:
        nursery.start_soon(fetch, url.format(i), headers, response_queue)
await response_queue.put(None)
```

After you download a URL, put the response into the queue:

```
async def fetch(url, headers, response_queue):
    print("Start: ", url)
    response = await s.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Add responses to queue
    await response_queue.put(response)
    print("Finished: ", url, len(response.content), response.status_code)
```

With the changes above, your fetch tasks will put responses into the queue. Now you need to read responses from the queue so you can process them. You might add a new function to do this:

```
async def process(response_queue):
    async for response in response_queue:
        if response is None:
            break
        # Do whatever processing you want here.
```

You should start this process function as a background task before you start any fetch tasks so that it will process responses as soon as they are received.

Read more in the [Synchronizing and Communicating Between Tasks](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#synchronizing-and-communicating-between-tasks) section of the Trio documentation.

Comment: This is a cleaner explanation. Except that `trio.Queue` always need a capacity. So instead of a marker, you can use a capacity bounded by the number of tasks (here `len(networkIds)`).

Comment: Note that Trio deprecated `Queue` in favour of `open_memory_channel`: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/history.html?highlight=trio.Queue#id40

Comment: `where would it even return to?`

seems to me that it should be returned to the nursery object after it exits its `with` block. its resources/tasks are cleaned up but the user could still call `nursery.results()` to get retvals from the now-closed tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adrien Clerc answer states: `trio.Queue` has been deprecated: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/history.html?highlight=trio.Queue#id40

For task communication in Trio see: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#using-channels-to-pass-values-between-tasks

Here's a full working minimal (removing the async url get request and replacing with a sleep) example for your use case using `open_memory_channel`

```
import datetime
import trio


async def main():
    network_ids = ["id1", "id2", "idn"]
    url = "https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/{0}/airMarshal?timespan=3600"
    send_channel, receive_channel = trio.open_memory_channel(len(network_ids))
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(producer, send_channel, url, network_ids)
        nursery.start_soon(consumer, receive_channel)


async def producer(send_channel, url, network_ids):
    async with send_channel:
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            for i in network_ids:
                nursery.start_soon(fetch, send_channel, url.format(i))


async def consumer(receive_channel):
    async with receive_channel:
        async for value in receive_channel:
            # Do your job here
            print(f"value received: {value} at time {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}")


async def fetch(send_channel, url):
    print(f"Start: {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}")
    await trio.sleep(1)
    response = f"response for {url}"
    await send_channel.send(response)
    print(f"Finished: {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

This prints:

```
Start: 2023-03-03 10:21:24.883787
Start: 2023-03-03 10:21:24.883787
Start: 2023-03-03 10:21:24.883787
Finished: 2023-03-03 10:21:25.887040
Finished: 2023-03-03 10:21:25.887040
Finished: 2023-03-03 10:21:25.887040
value received: response for https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/id1/airMarshal?timespan=3600 at time 2023-03-03 10:21:25.887040
value received: response for https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/id2/airMarshal?timespan=3600 at time 2023-03-03 10:21:25.887040
value received: response for https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/idn/airMarshal?timespan=3600 at time 2023-03-03 10:21:25.887040
```